# bash printing lines to STDOUT and deleting them

Tags: bash, stdout

I have an interactive script that I want to print some lines, overwrite them with blank lines and write some more:

```
    for host in "${!HOSTS[@]}"
    do
            echo "Running on ${HOSTS[$host]}:"
            ssh ${HOSTS[host]} "echo blah ; echo blah"
            echo -e "\e[4A"
            printf " %$((COLUMNS-1)).s\n" {1..3}
            echo -e "\e[4A"
    done
```

This is based that I will actually have 3 lines of previous output.

Is there a way to make it more dynamic? Finding out how many lines were printed and overwriting exactly those?

Thanks

Comment: To be honest, i never understand such needs. It you want use screen oriented scripts, here is the `dialog` package. If line oriented, enough to print `\r` and if multiline i would simply use the `clear` and start with a clear screen... It is worth playing witch such addressing?

Comment: a. for fun and knowledge. b. I cannot install anything. I would also prefer not to use clear as I still would like see the previous command line

Comment: If you iterating over the keys of an array but never use the key except to index the array, that's a sign you simply want to iterate over the array *values* instead.

Answer (score 3):

Put the output in a variable, and count the number of lines in the variable:

```
OUTPUT=$(ssh ${HOSTS[host]} "echo blah ; echo blah")
lines=$(echo "$OUTPUT" | wc -l) # count lines
echo "$OUTPUT" # echo it
```

After this you can use `$lines` to know how many lines to overwrite.

Comment: Yeah, thought of that, but it will print `$OUTPUT` in bulk. Obviously the script does more than just blah :).  Maybe to do it with a tee or some pipe?

Comment: You could do each bit of output like this, and add up the lines as you go, to know how many to clear.

Comment: I'm trying to do it with something like: `echo blah  | tee >(wc -c | read OUTPUT)`. But it doesnt work :(

Comment: You're reading the variable in a subshell, it doesn't affect the original shell.

Comment: That's probably why... Anyway, I was also looking to save on ssh commands, so splitting it, and count each command isn't so helpful for my current needs.

Comment: Why do you need to split it? As my answer shows, you can put multiple commands inside the `OUTPUT` assignment. The only issue is that nothing will appear on the screen until all the commands are done -- is that what's bothering you?

Comment: Yes :) some command take seconds to print. Others instant. The whole point is to show the user where it is at.